# Filtering output of tail in with Python

Tags: python, unix, command-line

A simple filtering script that looks pretty much like

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
  print line
```

doesn't print anything if output of `tail -f` piped through it but works fine with output of `cat`. `grep` however has no problems with `tail -f` so I guess I should somehow change the way the script handles input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to python(1) manpage:

> Note  that there is **internal buffering** in xreadlines(), readlines() and file-object  iterators  ("for  line  insys.stdin")  which  is  not  influenced by this option.  To work  around this, you will want to use "sys.stdin.readline()"  inside a "while 1:" loop.

Try following instead:

```
import sys

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```